# Confusion regarding Faraday's law

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Suppose we have a rectangular coil placed in a uniform magnetic field and the coil is rotated at a uniform speed. Now, we know that due to the change in the magnetic flux linked with the coil that an induced current flows. What is the force responsible for this? Is it the magnetic force or the electric force? If it is the magnetic force, then is there any electric field produced and thus a potential gradient (I mean similar to the potential gradient we have in case of a simple DC circuit)?

Answer (score 1):

Note first that there will be no current unless the ends of the coil are joined together, perhaps by an external resistive load.

The force giving rise to the current is the is the *magnetic* Lorentz force ($\vec F=q \vec v \times \vec B$) acting on free electrons in the two sides of the coil that are cutting magnetic flux.

Now to address your question, "is there any electric field produced and thus a potential gradient (I mean similar to the potential gradient we have in case of a simple dc circuit)?" Yes: in the two sides of the coil that are not cutting magnetic flux, and in the external load, the free electrons are forced through the wire by an $electric$ field arising from an imbalance of charge due to the (magnetic) e.m.f. described in the previous paragraph.

[Note that the electric field just discussed arises only indirectly from the cutting of magnetic flux. It is **not** an electric field arising from a changing magnetic field according to the Faraday-Maxwell equation, $\text{curl} \vec E =-\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}$, for the simple reason that $\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}=0$.]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. There exists an electric field due to changing magnetic flux and thus a potential gradient in the coil similar to the electric field we have in case of electrostatics.Only when there is changing magnetic field non-conservative electric field is produced where there can be no potential gradient.   This is what I have understood if it is correct then let me know.Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it right. The point about your coil rotating in a constant field is that the electromotive force is not due to a non-conservative electric field, but to the magnetic Lorentz force. The emf induced in a stationary coil through which the magnetic flux is changing because of changing flux density ($\vec B$) $is$ due to the non-conservative electric field! [This rather complicated state of affairs was one of the oddities that stimulated Einstein to develop the Special Theory of Relativity!]

Comment: please bear with my doubt. Suppose I have a pure inductor connected to an ac source V=V0sin(wt) due to which a current i flows.Now as per my book an opposing emf given by -Ldi/dt is induced and the writer proceeds with applying Kirchoff voltage law V-Ldi/dt=0 and then solving for i.What I don't get is since induced opposing emf is due to changing magnetic field the electric field should be non-conservative then how can we apply KVL as it is limited to conservative field.

Comment: (a) You are quite right that for an inductor the emf is due to magnetic flux density that changes with time, so the forces on the free charges in the coil are due to an induced non-conservative electric field. (b) The emf in the inductor causes an unbalanced charge distribution; putting it crudely, one end of the wire of the coil gets a negative charge and the other end a positive charge. These unbalanced charges give rise to a conservative electric field that exists both inside and outside the inductor. (Continued)

Comment: (c) Based on (b) above, there are at least two equivalent statements of KVL: (A) The algebraic sum of the pd's in a closed loop is zero. (B) The algebraic sum of the emfs in a closed loop is equal to the sum of the potential drops (in the components that aren't the seats of emfs). The equivalence is because in an ideal battery or inductor, if positive charge is urged inside it from terminal A to terminal C, C will be at a greater potential than A by an amount equal to the emf.

Answer (score 1):

The rotating coil with a changing magnetic flux linked with it has an electric field induced in it - Faraday’s law.

If there is a complete electrical circuit an induced current flows in the coil because of the induced electric field.

The direction of the induced current and the resulting magnetic field produced by the induced current is such as to oppose the change in the magnetic flux producing it - Lenz.

The induced current interacting with the applied magnetic field produces a force on the coil - Lorentz.
This force does not exist if there is no induced current even if there is an induced electric field, ie if there is a break in the coil.

That force will try and slow down the rotation of the coil if there are no other forces acting on the coil.

In terms of energy the kinetic energy of the coil is converted to heat - Ohmic heating due to the coil having resistance and a current passing through the coil.

If the coil is to maintain a constant speed of rotation then there must be an external forces/torque doing work on the coil.